# Change image onmouseover and onmouseout events work in IE but do not work in Chrome/FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Want to display another image onmouseover and onmouseout on my site. I have the following:

```
<img src="@(Model.ThumbPath)" alt='@Model.Description' 
     onmouseover='iconMouseOver(this,"@Model.ThumbInvPath")' 
                onmouseout='iconMouseOut(this,"@Model.ThumbPath")'/>
```

Called Javascript methods:

```
function iconMouseOver(targetImg, replaceImg) {
    $(targetImg).attr('src', replaceImg);
}

function iconMouseOut(targetImg, replaceImg) {
    $(targetImg).attr('src', replaceImg);
}
```

The code above works in IE but none of the other browsers. ( I know, right ? Usually it's other way around ). Images are displayed but mouse over/hover effects don't work.
What am I missing ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know if the iconMouseOver/Out events are even getting called in the other browsers?

Comment: write "return;" at the end of function. not tested but may work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've prepared you an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dhfj6/)

I'm using the jQuery hover method

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out when I get home tonight. Hopefully it'll work with partial views.

Comment: Problem with your example is that I don't have a static Image. That I can assign to .hover(). As you can see from my example above I'm passing specific images to the "hover"/mouseOver function and assigning what images passed in picture should be replaced on in-and-out. I wonder if there is a way your example can be implemented with what I'm doing here

Comment: Hi! I've I've undestood you, you only need to set the images using the data-imagesrc-x attributes